# How to get more ways of interrogating my data source from subsonic

Tags: subsonic

In the below link, Linq-To-Sql produces a range of methods to get data back based on various real-world needs (e.g. recent topics, etc).

How can I get Subsonic to produce me a set of classes which would interrogate and return data back from my data source in such a way? I get classes which really just present CRUD ops.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a link here but in general I'd say you can use SubSonic 3 in much the same way you can Linq to Sql. Here's some sample code:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Linq_Select_Queries

Other than that I'd need more specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it with SubSonic is to make a view with the way you want the data to be formatted, and then retrieve it with SubSonic.